# Spring Boot and Kotlin - Cannot find my ID

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm unable to get documents by Id (using Spring Boot and Mongo) - I've tried the following lines with no luck:

`sRepository.findById(songId)`

and

`query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(songId))`

I've added the `@Id` annotation in my model to specify the id field:

```
@Document(collection = "songs")
data class Song(
    @Id
    val id: String,
```

and in my mongo the document I've added looks like:

```
{
    "_id": "532132assad4a0",
    "code": "956743458",
    ...
```

The Mongo repository class:

```
@Repository
interface SongRepository : MongoRepository<Song, String>
```

Any help would be appreciated - rather confused by it.

FOUND THE ANSWER:

I had to add the annotation `@MongoId` instead of `@Id` as I was saving it as a string, didn't want any other conversion happening on it.
Found at the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.conventions.id-field

Comment: Have you tried `sRepository.findOne(songId)`? Check  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47217900/spring-boot-mongodb-search-by-id-returns-null) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48463457/spring-boot-mongodb-id-query) answers as well.

Comment: Checked those links already, nothing there that helped.

Comment: Can you show your mongo repository class?

Comment: @raestio - updated the post. Then I just Autowire it when I'm calling it.

Comment: @userMod2 It's better to put the solution as answer